# NMAP (or other) continuous port scan until it returns open?

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

Is there a way with nmap or anything else to do a continuous port scan, say on port 22, until the service comes up and the port is coming back as open?

Kind of like you may have an infinite ping going, timing out, to see when a host comes back up...but with port scanning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you can try a small script with netcat:

```
while true;do nc -zv 192.168.100.1 22;sleep 5;done
```

What this does is check if you can open a TCP connection to the SSH port every 5 seconds. If it does, you'll see this in the stdout:

```
Connection to 192.168.100.1 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Comment: Perfect solution. And perfectly portable, looks like it should work on OSX as well. Thanks

Comment: while true; will always repeat nc because there is no exit in the loop. In the loop there should be something that tests $? and exit when zero. Better checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982743)